# uri_for includes port number on redirects

Tags: perl, nginx, catalyst, starman

I'm attempting to implement a Catalyst application using nginx as a frontend web proxy for static files, and using Starman for my backend webserver.  (I could use Apache & FastCGI and it works just fine, but I'd really like to get the whole PSGI / Plack and Starman thing ironed out)

Starman starts up okay and can handle my requests just fine on `http://localhost:5000`.  When I fire up nginx to use as my front-end proxy, my urls become ugly and mangle with the port number (5000) whenever or wherever I use the `$c->uri_for` method.

Example :

```
$c->uri_for("/login")
becomes
http://myapp.example.com:5000/login 
rather than
http://myapp.example.com/login
```

I have some logs being created so I can see what `X-Forwarded-Host` and `X-Forwarded-For` are set as.  For normal requests, there are values set (coming from nginx), but whenever the `$c->uri_for` method is used, those values do not exist.

Has anyone else had this problem?
Am I missing something else in my configuration of either nginx or my Catalyst conf?

Thanks!

nginx config :

```
server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   myapp.example.com;

        location /static {
            root /data/users/MyApp/root;
            expires 30d;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }
    }
```

Event though this will be ran on the same physical server, in MyApp config I have set :

```
MyApp->config(using_frontend_proxy => 1)
```

Versions :

```
Catalyst : 5.80024
nginx : 0.7.67
Plack : 0.9942
Starman : 0.2006
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was in my `myapp.psgi` file.

from  [Catalyst::Engine::PSGI](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Catalyst-Engine-PSGI-0.10/lib/Catalyst/Engine/PSGI.pm) and look at `Plack::Middleware::ReverseProxy`:

```
...
use Plack::Builder;
use MyApp;

MyApp->setup_engine('PSGI');
my $app = sub { MyApp->run(@_) };

builder {
 enable_if { $_[0]->{REMOTE_ADDR} eq '127.0.0.1' } 
        "Plack::Middleware::ReverseProxy";
 $app;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the frontend was in a different host and adding

```
MyApp->config(using_frontend_proxy => 1)
```

did make a difference and solved the problem.

Comment: This is documented at https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst#PROXY-SUPPORT and should be the accepted answer as this is built into Catalyst, doesn't need to modify the generated `.psgi` file and can be set by local config.